# Trying to connect over local network to SQL Server

Tags: networking, sql-server, virtualbox

I have a developer edition of SQL server 2019 running on my machine. In virtual box I have a linux server that's connected to a local host-only virtual network. I can ping back and forth between the two machines, so they can talk back and forth. I have enabled tcp connections in SQL server. I have installed mssql-tools on the linux machine. I have also configured the Windows firewall to allow tcp through port 1433. If I run nmap on the Windows machine, port 1433 shows up in the list, but if I run nmap on the linux box directed at the windows host, the only thing that shows up is port 80. And if I curl from the linux box to the windows machine, I receive the webpage from the local IIS server that I have installed.

When I try to run sqlcmd from the linux box with the appropriate address, credentials, etc. though I receive a connection timeout. If I run wireshark on the windows host, though, I do see the request coming in over the virtual network connection to the windows box. There is just no answer from SQL server.

I have restarted SQL server after adjusting the tcp settings, but it looks to me like maybe it's still not listening on the appropriate port, or just hasn't started up the service?

Any troubleshooting tips to continue to try and figure this out?

netstat -a shows `TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           DESKTOP-IGUCNS1:0      LISTENING` on the windows box. I also tried turning the firewall off on the windows machine and no improvement there.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, never mind. A machine reboot finally did the trick. When all else fails, kick it.